# Session Handling in servlet using JSESSIONID cookie not getting session

Tags: java, session, servlets, cookies, jsessionid

I read that to persist session in servlet a **cookie gets saved at client side with the name of JSESSIONID**.
I checked it also and I found the cookie of **localhost** with the name of **JSESSIONID** with **some random String value**.

So I tried to create the session manually by creating the JSESSIONID cookie in the servlet but when I am trying to get the session it's not working.
What is happening here?
Is there anything else other than cookie(JSESSIONID) that gets stored soomewhere for the session creation? 
If not why I'm not able to get the session ?
Please Help.

Code that I used to create the cookie and get the session

```
package sessionHandling;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/sessionhandling")
public class SessionHandling extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    out.print("Hello Mr.! How are you?");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if(session != null){
        out.println("You are logged in.");

        out.println("session found with "+session.getId());
        out.println("session found with "+session.getLastAccessedTime());

    }else{
        //session = request.getSession(true);
        Cookie JSESSIONID = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", "12345");
        JSESSIONID.setMaxAge(-1);
        response.addCookie(JSESSIONID);
        System.out.println("Cookie Created");

        out.print("You are not logged in");
    }
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not responsible for creating or tracking the cookie. The servlet container looks after this for you.

As soon as you invoke:

```
   HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

or

```
   HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

then the servlet container will start maintaining the session for you (and generate the cookie as needed).

The `HttpSession` object is maintained in server memory between requests and is usually looked up by the session id. If you create the cookie yourself the server will not know anything about it or any associated HttpSession.

Answer (score 1):

Once you run your code , first time , session will be null and you will instruct the browser (or any other client) to create the JESSIONID cookie. Till here it is all correct.

Now, when you make the request again, browser (or any other client) will attach the cookie to the request and tomcat (or any other servlet engine) will receive the JESSIONID. Till here it is all fine.

But what now ? Tomcat (or any other servlet engine) will then search if it has any HttpSession object having sessionID "12345". Do you think it will be found ? No.

Why ? The code that you wrote above was only to Set cookie header in response message. It did not instructed tomcat(or any other servlet engine) to view this JSESSIONID named cookie as a session Id and create a corresponding HttpSession Object internally in Java Heap.

That's why we use `request.getSession()`. It instructs tomcat to do 2 things -

1. Whatever you did i.e. add the Set Cookie info in response by name JSESSIONID with a random ID.
2. Creates a corresponding HttpSession object and save it in memory (by default), so that next time when request comes, it can recognise that JESSIONID as a valid session ID by finding  a corresponding HttpSession object. This was missed by your code.